# Can I use RPM packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, package-management, rpm

A friend of mine uses RPM and has many custom in house developed packages of his own and wants to switch to Ubuntu.

The question he asked me was; Can I use RPM packages with Ubuntu instead of .deb ? as it is almost impossible recompiling all packages he has already.

Note: The question is about working **Natively** with RPM packages (not to convert RPM to deb using Alien)

Thanks.

Comment: With regards to your flag - the answers given in the dupe explain the only way currently to utilise RPM's.  Thus its a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Install an RPM Package on Ubuntu Linux

Installing software on Ubuntu usually entails using Synaptic or by using an apt-get command from the terminal. Unfortunately, there are still a number of packages out there that are only distributed in RPM format.

There’s a utility called Alien that converts packages from one format to the other. This doesn’t always mean that an rpm will work on your system, though. You will need to install some prerequisite software packages in order to install alien, however. These packages include gcc and make.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about Alien... what I understand is problems with Alien comes from dependencies. what if the custom RPM packages I talked about are self sufficient and has no dependencies? does this mean Alien will always work then?........also, away from converting, is there a way to natively work with RPM -without conversion I mean?